# Book on set theory

Tags: set-theory

I'm looking for a rigorous book on naive set theory that is heavy on proofs (with maybe some problem sets of proofs much like spivak's books for example) and points out what the flaws of naive set theory. 
I know it's very specific, but i've seen from other questions that there are a lot of books on set theory. Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you seen http://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ests-wh.pdf

Comment: I had never read that. Thank you. I will check those out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally liked "Discovering Modern Set Theory" by Just and Weese (2 parts), as a good elementary text book.

Or Hrbacek and Jech's Introduction to Set Theory is good too IMHO (it was my first book on set theory, actually).